# json_encode faster than Avro encoder in PHP (benchmark)

Tags: php, json, avro, benchmarking, jsonencoder

So everywhere I've been reading about how Avro encoding is faster than JSON, but when I ran my own tests I got totally different results. In my tests, which are nothing out of the ordinary, JSON was consistently and much much faster than Avro. Am I missing something here?

This is the serialize method for Avro:

```
public function serialize(array $documentArray)
    {
        $this->schemaID = 1;
        $parsedSchema = AvroSchema::parse(SCHEMA);

        // check if there's already an io datum writer in the local cache, if so use it
        if (isset($this->ioDatumWriterCache[$this->schemaID])) {
            $datumWriter = $this->ioDatumWriterCache[$this->schemaID];
        } else {
            $datumWriter = new \AvroIODatumWriter($parsedSchema);
            $this->ioDatumWriterCache[$this->schemaID] = $datumWriter;
        }

        // check if there's already a binary encoder in the local cache, if so use it
        if (isset($this->binaryEncoderCache[$this->schemaID])) {
            $encoder = $this->binaryEncoderCache[$this->schemaID];
        } else {
            $encoder = new \AvroIOBinaryEncoder($this->ioWriter);
            $this->binaryEncoderCache[$this->schemaID] = $encoder;
        }

        $datumWriter->write($documentArray, $encoder);

        return $this->ioWriter->string();
    }
```

and this is the one for JSON:

```
public function serialize(array $documentArray): string
    {
        try {
            return json_encode($documentArray, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            throw new ObjectIOException('JSON decode exception', 0, $ex);
        }
    }
```

I'm using phpbench to run the benchmarks.

The results (serializing the same set of data for both) are:

JSON Encoding Average Times:
1.685μs
1.642μs
1.637μs
1.642μs
1.637μs

Avro Encoding Average Times:
40.574μs
40.716μs
40.664μs
40.480μs
40.583μs

Comment: "everywhere I've been reading about how Avro encoding is faster than JSON" - I've never heard of Avro until now, and some quick searches aren't really showing much as it relates to PHP. Can you post what you've heard and where? The binary appears to run in a Docker environment, so I'd expect a little bit of overhead there regardless. Maybe it is better/faster for larger documents?

Comment: Agreed with the other commenter. I don't think avro claims to be more performant when serializing. The benefits of avro over json are things like reduced message sizes over the wire and schema evolution to name a few.

Comment: these are some of the articles I've seen https://www.nidhivichare.com/blog/avro-vs-json , https://blog.devgenius.io/serialization-performance-in-net-json-bson-protobuf-avro-a25e8207d9de , https://medium.com/@sarjerav/why-does-avro-serialization-outperform-json-serialization-eaa81ae7c725

but perhaps Chris is right, the difference might be noticeable only in large documents

Answer (score 0):

The language you are using and the data you are serializing makes a difference.

Your code systematically parse the schema every time you serialize! Is this essential?

In PHP json_encode is a language library function which is very fast. The Avro code is a PHP library (not nearly as fast).

What is a document array? The time used to convert integers, doubles ... to a JSON string is not negligible. On the other end, the time to convert the JSON string back to intergers and doubles is also not negligible.

In most compiled languages Avro serialisation would probably be faster than JSON. It is always more compact.